# Защитить POST от сокетов

Tags: php

Добрый вечер.

Имею страницу с 2мя изображениями, при клике на одно из них в file.php передается пост запрос вида: **left=1&right=2** , где 1 и 2 айдишники изображений.
Предположим мне важно чтобы в file.php передавались именно это значения, и важно чтобы никто не пытался передать post запросы со стороны.
Какими техниками обычно пользуются дабы предотвратить передачу post запросов со стороны?

Comment: Вообще, "*запрос вида: left=1&right=2*" - это больше не на POST, а на GET метод похож ;)

Comment: @Deonis, небольшой ликбез.

[По умолчанию](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1), при отправке запроса через веб-форму *любым методом*, в т.ч. и POST-методом, используется [`enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#ampersands-in-uris). Т.е. параметры запроса кодируются именно таким образом, как указано у ТС.

Comment: @Deonis в строковом проявлении POST не отличается от GET'a.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Эта проблема частично решается при помощи подписывании параметров. Алгоритм примерно следующий:

1. Генерируем секретное слово(пароль) при помощи которого будут подписываться ссылки и сохраняем его в настройках проекта.
2. Во время генерации ссылки(формы) создаем еще два параметра:

   - `timestamp` - время создания ссылки, т.е. текущее время.
   - `secure_token` - хэш от: все передаваемые параметры + timestamp + секретное слово
3. При получении запроса по сгенерированной ссылке проверяем:

   - Подпись. Т.е. повторно берем хэш по тому-же алгоритму, а затем сравниваем его с `secure_token`
   - Время генерации ссылки (параметр `timestamp`). Т.е. что бы `time() - timestamp` было не больше некой дельты (например 5 минут)
4. Если проверка выше прошла, значит все в порядке. Иначе выдаем пользователю ошибку.

Answer (score 3):

А сессию почему бы не использовать? А в файле file.php проверять ее наличие, и, при ее отсутствии, отфутболивать зашедшего на другую страницу?

Comment: В самой сессии и передавать `left` и `right` id изображений

Answer (score 2):

Боюсь что это не возможно, если обычный пользователь может нажать и отправить запрос то и скрипт это сможет. Можно конечно поставить проверку по рефферу, генеририровать рандомный ключ и отправлять его вместе с запросом (типа так капча) но все это не спасет от более менее нормального программиста.

Answer (score 2):

Генерировать на серверной стороне уникальный токен, сохранять в сессию, и выводить в форму в hidden поле, при получение запроса проверять на наличие и корректность токена.
Естественно, для каждого захода на страницу с формой токен должен быть уникальным, например, брать хеш от логин+секрет+время, иначе защита теряет смысл.

Comment: Все ровно взломаю.

Comment: А если токен будет создаваться совместно сервером и клиентом **для каждого** запроса, с использованием известного только клиенту и серверу ключа ? Ключ не передается по сети.

Как, *zeronesequece...*, взломаете ?

Answer (score 0):

Понимаете, в общем случае, мы не можем точно сказать "от кого" пришел запрос. Был ли это настоящий пользователь, нажавший кнопку в браузере, либо скрипт ("с сокетом" :).
Тупо на ваш пример: я просто возьму GET вашей сгенеренной странички со всеми вашими hidden полями и пошлю скриптом вам их обратно.
Совет: Ставьте sleep в backend'e, чтобы я очень быстро не мог делать вам POST'ы :)